# Return not being called from super in parent Activity

Tags: java, android, superclass, super

I have an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` implemented in a parent `Activity` that returns if the position if `<=` to zero. When I subclass this `Activity` and override the `OnItemClickListener`, call `super`, then retrieve the item from my `Adapter`, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` thrown. But this occurs because the `return` isn't called before `Adapter.getItem` is called from my subclass. In other words:

**This works**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    final Foo foo = mAdapter.getItem(position);
}
```

**This doesn't work**

---

**In my parent `Activity`**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position <= 0) {
        return;
    }
}
```

**In my subclass**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
    final Foo foo = mAdapter.getItem(position);
}
```

But if I log `OnItemClickListener.onItemClick` in my parent `Activity` and just leave out `Adapter.getItem` in my subclass, the `Exception` isn't thrown and the log prints.

So, I suppose I just don't understand why `super` and `return` aren't being called beforehand, even though it looks like they should be. Does `super` just not operate like this? Am I just completely overlooking something here? Just to be clear, the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means nothing in this case. It occurs because I'm using a very customized `Adapter`.

Comment: super.onItemClick is just any other method call. when it returns, it does not have any impact on the calling method.

Comment: Oh, I guess I figured it carried over.